# Is there any specific command for create angular 4 project by angular cli?

Tags: typescript, npm, angular-cli, angular

I updated all the packages using npm as below

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest 
@angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest 
@angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest 
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest 
@angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

now as usual using 'ng new' can i create a angular 4 project?

Comment: Seems to be the default for the latest angular CLI version https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3962#issuecomment-290449779

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest angular cli `npm install -g @angular/cli` The latest as of this post is `1.0.0`

By default `ng new` will generate angular 4 app.

To force angular 4 app, use 'ng new app --ng4'

Comment: ng new sampleapp --ng4

Comment: Angular cli 1.0.0 uses angular 4 by default. Edited the answer to include the --ng4 flag.